# Questions regarding receiving 3G calls on my IDEOS

Tags: 2.2-froyo, video-calling, huawei-u8150

My Android device is 3G capable, but does not have a front-facing camera. I am on a 3G network and I don't see any "video call" option in contacts. I'm wondering if I will be able to receive video calls so that I can just see them or maybe show my primary camera (back of the phone; the only camera) to them?

Also, if that was possible, can I toggle the camera off/on DURING the 3g call?
And does "data packet" need to be enabled to receive 3G calls?

EDIT: My device is Huawei IDEOS u8150 running Android 2.2 and if 3G video calls are not supported, can I find some custom ROM suitable for mine that can do this with the existing camera or some other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to receive a 3G video call from another phone, assuming what you are looking for is the operator backed 3G-324M solution that is available on most 3G phones (not including iPhone or Android).
3G-324M as a solution doesn't run over IP and requires a tighter integration between operating system, modem and application.
You can read more on the technicalities here: http://www.radvision.com/Resources/Developers/White-Papers/android_integration.htm

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the application used to make the video call. Some applications may tell you that you don't have a front facing camera and may not work. Some may allow you to use the back camera, I am not sure.

The best option is to try the application and see if you can make/receive calls.

**[edit]**
[VideoCall Radar](https://market.android.com/details?id=air.RadarVideoCall) is an app that will allow you make Video Calls without a front facing camera, but, like all the other apps, the person your calling has to have the application too.

Comment: im sorry, what do you mean by "application"? android calling system is stock.. As I've stated before, I cannot find the "video call" option when calling.. are there any workaround?

Comment: android does not have "video calling" out of the box. there are applications like "Gtalk" that supports it in android 2.3 (on devices with Front Facing Cameras), and there are applications like QiK,Fring and Tango that do video calling.

Comment: But those are not true 3G.. like you stated, they require the person calling to have the app. however, the built in "video calling" feature on nokia and sony etc are based on the popular 3G video calling protocol 3G-324M. I need an app that can implement this

Comment: They are "true 3G", if they work on a 3G network. I think you  are a little confused exactly what 3G is, the "3G" part of that protocol just means the mobile data network. While it is true that these apps may not be "true 3G-324M" compliant. I dont know if these apps implement the protocol or not. Android, AFAIK, does not have a built-in stack for 3G-324M. A company named "RadVision" seems to implemented a Stack for 3G-324M, but i was unable to find any applications that support that protocol on android.

Comment: I understand what 3G is , I was just haste in referring it as "true 3G" lol ; 3G is mobile data network, what im saying is , this 3G-324M voice/video service is widely acknowledged and supported by telecom providers here so I too want to enjoy the services.. seems like I can probably wait once this becomes available in future android versions or probably pop up in some custom ROM/ apps?